# Cascading Hierarchical Join Conditions

Tags: sql-server, join, database-schema, hierarchy, intersection

I'm currently putting together a schema that will be responsible for storing products, prices and margins.

The crux of the problem I'm having is how best to handle multiple scenarios.

### Definitions - All these are fields in the Link (Intersection) table

- Product - A widget
- Margin - An data structure that represents how to alter the purchase
  price to determine retail price. (complex enough to require a
  separate table)
- Supplier - Someone who supplies us with a Product
- Authority - Someone the supplier is beholden to
- Client - Someone we will retail to
- ClientGroup - A collection of Clients

Some of these are optional. There will always be a Product-Margin mapping. 
The other fields exist to define more specific relationships.

The rules will be applied with a hierarchy.

Examples:

1. Product **"Foo"** has a Margin of 10% (applies to all clients)
2. For ClientGroup "*Group A*" **Foo** has a Margin of 8%
3. For Client "Bob's Burgers" who is a member of "*Group A*" **Foo** has a margin of 6%

That would be covered by 3 rows, with the following fields populated (un-populated fields are null)

1. Product-Margin
2. ClientGroup-Margin
3. Client-Margin

Rule 3 is the most specific, and so would take precedence.

Is this link table to best way to store these hierarchical relationships?
If not, what is?

What is the best way of structuring a query to take advantage of this? I've written a query using temp tables and conditional logic but I cant help but think I'm square-pegging SQL and there's a better way of structuring the query.

I'd like to keep as much of the logic in SQL and out of the business logic.

In other words, the app can call a stored procedure, passing in the Product, and Client plus optionally Authority and /or Supplier and receive the appropriate Margin.

Comment: why hierarchy? it's jus relationships. Make some left outer joins and sort it in order like that: 'order by case when ProductId is null then 1 when ClientID is null then 2 else 3 end', and get just top1 of records

Answer (score 1):

I think in your examples 2 and 3 product should also be populated, otherwise that margin is applied to all products for the client or client group.

The query to get results could be something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Margin
FROM <table>
WHERE Product = @Product
AND COALESCE(Client,'') = COALESCE(@Client,Client,'')
AND COALESCE(ClientGroup,'') = COALESCE(@ClientGroup,ClientGroup,'')
ORDER BY Client DESC, ClientGroup DESC
```

@ - parameters passed to stored procedure. I don't know if your solution will require joins instead but you could change the where conditions to joins.

This assumes product is always passed as parameter, others are optional (you can add Supplier and Authority there).
Order by desc client means rows that are not null appear on top, if client column is null for all rows then theres the same logic for client group.

Or you can use the order by method suggested in the comment by James B

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input folks, the solution for the hierarchical behaviour that I wanted looks something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1
FROM MarginLink
WHERE
  (
(-- Client selection
  (ClientId = @clientId)
  OR
  ClientGroupId = (SELECT ClientGroupId FROM ClientGroupClient WHERE ClientId = @clientId)
)
AND
(--Product Selection
  (@productID BETWEEN ProductIdFrom AND ProductIdTo)
  OR
  (ProductTypeId = @productTypeID)
  OR
  (ProductIdFrom IS NULL  AND ProductIdTo IS NULL )
)

AND
(-- Supplier
  (SupplierId = @supplierId)
  OR
  (MarginLink.SupplierId IS NULL)
)
AND
(-- Authority
  (AuthorityId = @authorityId)
  OR
  (MarginLink.AuthorityId IS NULL)
)

)
ORDER BY  ClientId DESC, ClientGroupId DESC,  ProductIdFrom DESC, ProductIdTo DESC, ProductTypeId DESC, SupplierId DESC, AuthorityId DESC
```